# CakePHP variable parsing change

Tags: php, variables, cakephp

I have a strange problem; I have a variable, as follows:

```
$postBSGlobal = $post['Post']['B/S']
```

Which, when debugged, correctly delivers

```
"B"
```

But, later on the value magically changes to

```
"1"
```

Without me manipulating the variable in any way.

I need the string-value for this statement:

```
if ($userId <> $post['Post']['OWNER'] && $postBSGlobal = 'B'){
    echo "Dein Verdienst:";
};
```

Today my app is completely unusable due to this problem. Maybe the PHP-version on my managed server has changed? How can I prevent PHP from returning the "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a single = instead of ==. Change it to:

`$postBSGlobal == 'B'`

Comment: @Karl Can you show the code where it's outputting "1"? While the single instead of double equal is a problem, it wouldn't change the value to 1...that must be happening further down in your script.

Comment: Jesus, you saved my life! It was in correspondence with H = '0' statements which blew up some certain branches ... Thanks!!!